# Permissions to ports Alfresco

Tags: linux, permissions, tcp, cifs, alfresco

When I restart Alfresco, it starts... I got the page... But on the logs I got the error:

```
 2015-11-10 09:58:55,282  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default]
 2015-11-10 09:58:55,291  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [CIFS Server] [SMB] Server error : org.alfresco.jlan.server.config.InvalidConfigurationException: Error initializing TCP-IP SMB session handler, Permissão negada
 2015-11-10 09:58:55,301  ERROR [org.alfresco.fileserver] [CIFS Server] Error from JLAN
 org.alfresco.jlan.server.config.InvalidConfigurationException: Error initializing TCP-IP SMB session handler, Permissão negada
    at org.alfresco.jlan.smb.server.nio.NIOCifsConnectionsHandler.initializeHandler(NIOCifsConnectionsHandler.java:259)
    at org.alfresco.jlan.smb.server.SMBServer.run(SMBServer.java:479)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-11-10 09:58:55,360  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default] complete
```

How can I see if the user running Alfresco have permissions to those ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When started, Alfresco tries to bind on TCP ports 139 and 445 and UDP port 137 for the CIFS file sharing service.

These ports are in the unix privileged port range (<1024), so only a service started by the root can listen to these ports.

Depending on your distribution you may need to start the service with sudo (sudo service alfresco start) or start the service as a root user.